# The best way of reducing a property value from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to discover the most concise line of code that iterates through a simple array of objects and adds up the total value of a specific property that all objects have.

Take this array of objects for example:

```
const reviews = [
    {
      "name": "Joe Bloggs",
      "comment": "I liked it. Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "rating": 4,
      "date": "22 April 2020",
      "init": true,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Nick Smyth",
      "comment": "Great, thanks.",
      "rating": 4.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Mary Manson",
      "comment": "Amazing - consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus.",
      "rating": 5,
      "date": "07 March 2020",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Rachel Stevens",
      "comment": "Pretty good. Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      "rating": 4.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Jack Hawthorn",
      "comment": "Aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      "rating": 4,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Jacob Haywood",
      "comment": "Awful. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      "rating": 1,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Ben Stiller",
      "comment": "Thanks a lot.",
      "rating": 4.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Xiao Wei",
      "comment": "Great, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 4.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "John Harwood",
      "comment": "Rubbish - quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 2,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Jackie Chan",
      "comment": "Not great - quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 2.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Chuck Norris",
      "comment": "A poor 1.5 - quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 1.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Duncan Jones",
      "comment": "Satisfactory. Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 3,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Peter Lahm",
      "comment": "Was ok. Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 3.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Simon Arnold",
      "comment": "Nice - quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 4,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Claire Pullen",
      "comment": "Great - quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 4.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    }
  ]
```

Each object has a 'rating' property, and I wanted a variable of the total of all of these properties - so I wrote this, which works:

```
var correct = reviews.map(review => review.rating).reduce((a, b) => a + b); // correctly returns 53
```

But the above feels too verbose, so I tried to just use the reduce method on each object property rather than mapping to get each value in an array and then reduce that array to one value:

```
var incorrect = reviews.reduce((total, cur) => total + cur.rating); // incorrectly returns "[object Object]4.554.5414.54.522.51.533.544.5"
```

Why does the above not also return 53? Is there a way of fixing this so that it can only use the reduce method to return 53?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Forgot - codepen: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/zYvrpdY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to initialize the counter variable **total** to 0:

```
var incorrect = reviews.reduce((total, cur) => total + cur.rating, 0);
```

Otherwise, in the first iteration, the total variable will hold the value of the first element of the array instead of 0.

Refer to the [Array.prototype.reduce documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

> **initialValue**: A value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used as the initial accumulator value and skipped as currentValue.

Comment: ohh, hence why it displayed "object object". Didn't know about this - thank you!

Comment: Yes. If you sum an object with a number or a string, the object gets converted into its string representation, which is "[object Object]" in this case. So you finally end up with a giant string instead of a number.

Answer (score 1):

`let sum = reviews.reduce(function (total, currentValue) {
    return total + currentValue.rating;
}, 0);`